# GKE ingress; apply rewrite to specific service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Given this yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: admin
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /admin/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /auth/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

I would like the `rewrite-target` to only apply to the service `admin`. Requests to `keycloak` should not be affected. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate out ingress file or config, just make sure you keep the different name

So you can you create **TWO** ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: admin
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /admin/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

**Ingress**: **2** with different config, you can edit anything as per need now remove annotation.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: keycloak
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /auth/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

If you want to store everything in a single YAML file you can also do it by merging them with `---`.

Answer (score 1):

User [Harsh Manvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5525824/harsh-manvar)'s answer is good and shows the correct solution. But I am going to expand it a bit and tell you why. Always create deployments that are as little interdependent as possible. For example, if you need to change something in the `keycloak`, it shouldn't have any effect on `admin`. Additionally, if the ingress breaks down, you will have 2 broken services instead of one. You should practically always create one ingress to one service.

Additionally, you may want to create completely different rewrite rules. Then, creating separate ingress will be a very good idea. Look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1065154/nginx-ingress-rewrite-rule).

See also [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) about rewrite rules.